# since saving file in office 365 getting error while running macro in 2013 version

Tags: vba, ms-word

hello a macro i haven't written but editted a few times in word VBA stopped working in word 2013 after saving the file using a word 365, i am trying to figure out why but i can't wrap my head arround it.

When running the macro it crashes and gives me an error that an project or library is missing.
(pardon my usage of terms i have a dutch word, so i have to translate it)

when i inspect the vba code a sub is selected and the var "i" in a for loop is selected.
i can't find if this is a known problem on google, so i was hoping someone here might know.

if you need any more information please feel free te let me know. i will provide it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a VBA project it automatically creates references to the essential object libraries. If the project is later opened, or used, in a newer version of the application the references are automatically updated to any required newer library.

This does **not** happen in reverse, i.e. object libraries will not be automatically amended to an older version. It is for this reason that you should **always** do development using the oldest version of Office in which your code needs to work.

For O2013 the required Word and Office libraries are version 15. For O365 the required libraries are version 16.

You can solve your problem by editing the file in O2013 and resetting the references. You do this from the Tools menu in the Visual Basic Editor (VBE) and selecting References. This will show you a dialog similar to this:

[image: screenshot of References dialog]

You may need to scroll down the list quite a way until you find the entries for the Microsoft Word and Microsoft Office libraries. Then just click in the box to select the relevant library.

Comment: thanks a lot! i have been trying things for days, this fixed it. just disabled the 16.0 and activated the 15.0 and it works like a charm again.